# It is possible to do a "SUM" subquery or what should be done?

Tags: mysql, sql

I´m trying to get some results with this query, the issue is when I try to use "GROUP BY c.campus" without YEAR(a.period_end), and obviously get the results grouped by campus, plus sorting them properly like "2012, 2013, 2014, 2015", the problem is EndYear mixes, not displaying all the years... Thanks in advance.

**Query by now:**

```
SELECT DISTINCT a.user, a.service, GROUP_CONCAT(b.account) accounts,
YEAR(a.period_end) AS EndYear,
SUM(a.consum) AS SumConsumEngy,
SUM(a.cost) AS SumCostEngy, c.campus
FROM `sdspanel1`.`pdc_consum_engy` a
INNER JOIN `sdspanel1`.`ctrl_services` b ON(a.servicio = b.id)
INNER JOIN `sdspanel1`.`pdc_services_engy` c ON(c.accuont = b.account)
WHERE c.campus IS NOT NULL AND c.campus <> '' 
AND a.period_end IS NOT NULL AND a.period_end <> ''
GROUP BY YEAR(a.period_end), c.campus, b.account, a.service, a.user
ORDER BY YEAR(a.period_end) ASC ;
```

**Select Results by now:**

```
 user    service accounts  EndYear SumConsumEngy SumCostEngy   Campus
  4         14   191,191   2012     9919293      33339493     cname1
  4         23   238,388   2012     9283182      31931993     cname1
  4         14   191,191   2013     999293       3939493      cname1
  4         14   191,191   2013     991293       939493       cname1
  4         23   238,388   2014     9183182      31432993     cname2
  4         23   238,388   2012     9083182      31731993     cname2
  4         14   191,191   2012     9999293      36539403     cname2
  4         23   238,388   2013     9283182      32931923     cname2
  4         14   191,191   2013     9919293      33039843     cname2
  4         23   238,388   2014     9283182      31231993     cname2
```

Let me explain better or so, basically is to group by Campus, "SUM" "again" or by any other query or means the SumConsEngy and SumCostEngy, EndYear should be "ORDERED BY YEAR(a.period_end) ASC", SConsum#### and SCost#### should be the new sum of years to the corresponding campus. When I try the query I have, to only group by "c.campus", it doesn´t show all the years.

**What I ask for is something like this:**

```
 user service  accounts  EndYear SumConsumEngy SumCostEngy   Campus
  4   snumbers acnumbers   2012   SConsum2012  SCost2012     cname1
  4   snumbers acnumbers   2013   SConsum2013  SCost2013     cname1
  4   snumbers acnumbers   2014   SConsum2014  SCost2014     cname1
  4   snumbers acnumbers   2015   SConsum2015  SCost2015     cname1
  4   snumbers acnumbers   2016   SConsum2016  SCost2016     cname1
  4   snumbers acnumbers   2011   SConsum2011  SCost2011     cname2
  4   snumbers acnumbers   2012   SConsum2012  SCost2012     cname2
  4   snumbers acnumbers   2013   SConsum2013  SCost2013     cname2
  4   snumbers acnumbers   2014   SConsum2012  SCost2012     cname2
  4   snumbers acnumbers   2015   SConsum2012  SCost2012     cname2
  4   snumbers acnumbers   2016   SConsum2012  SCost2012     cname2
```

and so on...

Comment: If you don't group by year, the year in the results will be an (effectively) random one chosen from the values encountered for the fields that are grouped by.

Comment: Please explain better  .. i don't understand well your goal .. you need yoy result by now order by year?

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to remove `b.account, a.service, a.user` from your `GROUP BY` and maybe use `GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT b.account)`.

Comment: Gonna try your answer